# Method to use a UDF to return a Range as String to be used in Lookup Functions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

For my problem, I have a UDF which accepts a string and using select case it then returns the string reference to the specified array. The return string is a reference to a sheet and range array in the following form:

> 'WorksheetExample'!$B$1:$E$44

This UDF is nested within the VLookup/Match in my table to give the correct reference for that case.

```
Public Function EquipCatRNG(tag As String, tagOrCatRef As String)

'Hardcoded Category Ranges for Matches
Dim tagRef, catRef As String
Dim subfix As String
subfix = Left(tag, 1)
Select Case subfix
    Case "E"
    'Range for heat exchanger info, 'Heat Exchangers Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$J$53
    tagRef = "'Heat Exchangers Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$J$1"
    catRef = "'Heat Exchangers Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$B$53"
    Case "P"
        If InStr(tag, "Drive") > 0 Then
        tagRef = "'Pumps And Drives Template (EDS)'!$B$44:$G$44"
        catRef = "'Pumps And Drives Template (EDS)'!$B$44:$B$68"
        Else
        tagRef = "'Pumps And Drives Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$G$1"
        catRef = "'Pumps And Drives Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$B$42"
        End If
    Case "T"
        If InStr(tag, "Internals") > 0 Then
        tagRef = "'Towers Template (EDS)'!$B$46:$E$46"
        catRef = "'Towers Template (EDS)'!$B$46:$B$68"
        Else
        tagRef = "'Towers Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$E$1"
        catRef = "'Towers Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$B$44"
        End If
    Case "R"
        tagRef = "'Reactors Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$C$1"
        catRef = "'Reactors Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$B$61"
    Case "H"
        tagRef = "'Heaters Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$C$1"
        catRef = "'Heaters Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$B$45"
    Case "V"
        If InStr(tag, "Internals") > 0 Then
        tagRef = "'Vessels Template (EDS)'!$B$45:$F$45"
        catRef = "'Vessels Template (EDS)'!$B$45:$B$64"
        Else
        tagRef = "'Vessels Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$F$1"
        catRef = "'Vessels Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$B$43"
        End If
End Select
    tagOrCatRef = LCase(tagOrCatRef)
    If tagOrCatRef = "tag" Then
        EquipCatRNG = tagRef
    Else
        EquipCatRNG = catRef
    End If

End Function
```

Any help is appreciated, I would also be fine with passing the Range directly from the UDF instead of returning a string and then performing some operation to utilize it in the formula. Thank you.

EDIT for Clarity:
This function passes the String successfully but it is not working as a valid reference in the Vlookup/Match functions in my table. I need to know how I either: 
1. Perform a formula operation on the returned string post-UDF so that the Vlookup accepts it as a valid reference?
2. Pass it initially as a range?

Comment: What is your question ??

Comment: Sorry about that, edited for clarity.

Comment: Perhaps instead of strings, set them to `Range`? (`Set tagRef = Worksheets("Vessels Template (EDS)").Range("$B$1:$C$1")`, or whatever  Edit: Hang on - how are you going to use the result of this UDF, please give an example of how you'll call the VLOOKUP after you get the string.

Comment: Show your `VLOOKUP` formula.  My guess is that you did not enclose your string within the `INDIRECT` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the UDF 'in-line' inside another worksheet function, you need to Set the UDF to the range.

```
Public Function EquipCatRNG(tag As String, tagOrCatRef As String) as range

'Hardcoded Category Ranges for Matches
Dim tagRef As range, catRef As range
Dim subfix As String
subfix = Left(tag, 1)
Select Case subfix
    Case "E"
        'Range for heat exchanger info, 'Heat Exchangers Template (EDS)'!$B$1:$J$53
        Set tagRef = worksheets("Heat Exchangers Template (EDS)").Range("B1:J1")
        Set catRef = worksheets("Heat Exchangers Template (EDS)").Range("B1:B53")
    Case "P"
        If InStr(tag, "Drive") > 0 Then
          Set tagRef = worksheets("Pumps And Drives Template (EDS)").Range("B44:G44")
          Set catRef = worksheets("Pumps And Drives Template (EDS)").Range("B44:B68")
        Else
          Set tagRef = worksheets("Pumps And Drives Template (EDS)").Range("B1:G1")
          Set catRef = worksheets("Pumps And Drives Template (EDS)").Range("B1:B42")
        End If
    Case "T"
        'etc, etc, etc
         ...

End Select

    tagOrCatRef = LCase(tagOrCatRef)
    If tagOrCatRef = "tag" Then
        Set EquipCatRNG = tagRef
    Else
        Set EquipCatRNG = catRef
    End If

End Function
```

Used on a worksheet, this would look like,

```
=MATCH("abc", EquipCatRNG("E", "Tag"), 0)
```

Comment: Nice answer. Just an error `Dim tagRef As range, catRef As range`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I hadn't planned to build a full test bench and missed that typo.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. Out of curiosity is there any way to make the returned string back into a valid reference? I understand Indirect() would work if it only returned an address local to the worksheet but what about referencing different worksheets in the workbook?